# How to access attention values in attention decoder of seq2seq_model to plot bleu score

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a language translation model.
     1. I want to visualize data as mentioned in http://www.wildml.com/2016/01/attention-and-memory-in-deep-learning-and-nlp/ using bleu score.

```
2.  
for a in xrange(num_heads):
    with variable_scope.variable_scope("Attention_%d" % a):
      y = linear(query, attention_vec_size, True)
      y = array_ops.reshape(y, [-1, 1, 1, attention_vec_size])
      # Attention mask is a softmax of v^T * tanh(...).
      s = math_ops.reduce_sum(
          v[a] * math_ops.tanh(hidden_features[a] + y), [2, 3])
      a = nn_ops.softmax(s)
      # Now calculate the attention-weighted vector d.
      d = math_ops.reduce_sum(
          array_ops.reshape(a, [-1, attn_length, 1, 1]) * hidden,
          [1, 2])
      ds.append(array_ops.reshape(d, [-1, attn_size]))
  return ds
```

how can modify the code to retreiw the "a" values for visualization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to save the reference to those tensors in a python list. And then pass the python list to the `session.run` function. The result will be a list with the numpy values of those tensors.